# Are png and jpeg images allowed in an android app?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, png, jpeg

Newbie question. Is it permissible to use png and jpeg images in an android application, or can users of android smartphones have problems due to different screens?

Comment: Both formats are supported natively on Android.  Can you have problems due to screen size?  Depends on what you're doing with them.  We'd need details on how you want to display them.

Comment: Sorry for my English. The problem is that I'm worried that users have different screens and the PNG image will not be displayed correctly.

Comment: How are you displaying them?  A small button?  Full screen?  Do you want it scaled?  Cropped?  How do you want it scaled- keeping or losing the aspect ratio?  To fit the x, y, or both dimensions?  We need a detailed usecase, not just that you'll be using an image file.  I can tell you that any issues you have will generally be issues with both jpg and png.

Comment: No, not full screen. There will be cropped images on 1/3 of the user's screen. I would like the quality not to be lost too much, and most importantly, the picture should be in its place. SVG is not very suitable, as the image quality is not satisfactory.

Comment: So 1/3 of the screen and I assume aspect ratio scaling (you keep the same ratio of width:height.  Otherwise things get out of proportion).  Either of them can do that without an issue.  Use the Android resource system and provide the images at multiple resolutions, probably xxhdpi and hdpi as a minimum and you should be ok.  Remember its better for images to scale down slightly than up if you can (its easier to remove data than add it and avoid pixelation)

Answer (score 1):

png, jpeg, gif , svg, vector images all allowed in Android. All smartphone support them.